Terraform unable to run after converting service connection to workload identity
I have had my service connection converted to workload identity and now I'm getting these authorization errors:

I added in the use_oidc = true option as per the documentation:
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_oidc

I've added the use_oidc = true option into the provider "azurerm" section. I've also tried adding it into the backend as per the documentation but none of the configurations have been successfull for me. Has anybody cracked this problem yet? Any help greatly appreciated :)
PS, I'm using the TerraformTaskV4@4 task


How are you authenticating to the backend storage Account? Are you using an access key or Azure AD?

To be honest I still don't fully understand the difference. I've tried both ways (I believe) following this documentation link for auth method Service Principal or User Assigned Managed Identity via OIDC (Workload identity federation)

As per the documentation, if you are using use_azuread_auth = true and use_oidc = true to access a storage account, you need to authenticate via Azure Active Directory authentication by passing the client_id, subscription_id, and tenant_id. Please refer to the section titled Connect to Storage Account with Azure Active Directory authentication in the same documentation

To authenticate with a service principal, you need to provide the required parameters client_id, client_secret, subscription_id, and tenant_id in the backend block.

    terraform {
      backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name  = "RG_Name"          
        storage_account_name = "venkatstorage"                            
        container_name       = "venkat"                               
        key                  = "prod.terraform.tfstate"                
        use_oidc             = true                              
        client_id            = "xxxxxx" 
        subscription_id      = "xxxxx"  
        tenant_id            = "xxxxxxxx"
        client_secret        = "xxxxxxx"  
        use_azuread_auth     = true 
                                          
      }
    }
    
    provider "azurerm"{
        features {}
        skip_provider_registration = "true"
        subscription_id      = "1234566-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f"
        use_oidc        = true   
        use_cli         = false 
    }

Output:

If you are using any pipeline, make sure to set the service principal details in environment by following the Stack Link by quadroid
Reference: Stack Link1
Configuring the Service Principal in Terraform

Hi Venkat, thanks for responding. I would rather not have the client secret in my code. So according to the docs if I leave out use_azuread_auth option I can use the access key right? But if I try this it still fails. How can you do it without using the client secret in your code?

I'm able to access the .tfstate using an access key. Here are the Terraform code and Portal results.

I hope this helps you to resolve the issue?.

Hi Venkat, not really. The reason for us converting to Workload identity federation (OIDC) is so we no longer need to specify secrets or access keys correct? From what I can see in the documentation under Service Principal or User Assigned Managed Identity via OIDC (Workload identity federation) no client secret or access keys are defined. So my question is how can I make my terraform code work now that I have converted to workload identity federation without needing to specify client secret or access key in code

Refer to this link : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introduction-to-azure-devops-workload-identity-federation-oidc-with-terraform/#how-to-use-workload-identity-federation-in-an-azure-devops-pipeline-with-the-terraform-task and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_oidc

Those are the links I am referencing too. But the configuration in those links does not seem to work for me unfortunately

It looks like the document saying wrong, I tried the same, but its not working for me: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm

That would be a shame. I have reached out for some additional help. If I reach any conclusion I will post it here too. Thanks for thinking along and discussing Venkat!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I created a Microsoft support ticket, they were able to confirm that this is not supported but could not comment on the Terraform issues as this is a 3rd party tool.
I also reached out to Databricks and they were able to confirm that this is not supported and to create a feature request.
